# functions calls inside dom-repeat only executed once

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

We cannot get this simple use case running with polymer@1.4.0. We have a list of items. If user click on an item, an icon before the item will be shown. Also a specific `is-selected` class will be added to this item.

The list will be rendered with a dom-repeat. Each list item looks like:

```
{
  "label": "Item 1",
  "value": 0
}
```

If the user click in that item, we store the value in variable `selectedValue`. For some reason, the dom-repeat will not be rerendering. So the functions isSelected and getSelectedClass only will be called initially. But not after click-interaction. We already tried to use the `this.$.listItems.render();` inside the selectItem-function. But also have to effect. How we can handle this?

Our current code:

```
<dom-module id="selectable-list">
  <template>
    <style is="custom-style" include="selectable-list-styles"></style>
    <ul id="selectable-list">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]" id="itemList">
        <li class$="{{getSelectedClass(item)}}">
          <template is="dom-if" if="{{isSelected(item)}}">
            <iron-icon icon="sanitas-icons:check"></iron-icon>
          </template>
          <button type="button" on-click="selectItem">{{item.label}}</button>
        </li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </template>

  <script>
    var SELECTED_CLASS = 'is-selected';

    Polymer({

      is: 'selectable-list',

      properties: {
        items: {
          type: Array,
          value: []
        },
        selectedValue: {
          type: Object,
          notify: true,
          reflectToAttribute: true
        }
      },

      selectItem: function(event){
        this.selectedValue = event.model.item.value;
      },


      /**
       * check if a list item is selected
       *
       * @param {object} item
       * @returns {boolean}
       */
      isSelected: function(item){
        return item.value === this.selectedValue;
      },


      /**
       * get selected class if item is selected
       * @param {object} item
       * @returns {string}
       */
      getSelectedClass: function(item){
        return this.isSelected(item) ? SELECTED_CLASS : '';
      }

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `dom-if` and `dom-repeat` do not get re-triggered once you select some item as both of them depends on `item` which do not change. So the simple solution will be to add `selectedValue` also as variable to your functions

```
<li class$="{{getSelectedClass(item, selectedValue)}}">
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{isSelected(item,selectedValue)}}">
```

and in js

```
isSelected: function(item, selectedValue){
  return item.value === selectedValue;
},

getSelectedClass: function(item, selectedValue){
  return this.isSelected(item, selectedValue) ? SELECTED_CLASS : '';
}
```

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+v1.4.0/components/">

<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="selectable-list">
  <template>
    <style is="custom-style" include="selectable-list-styles"></style>
    <ul id="selectable-list">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]" id="itemList">
        <li class$="{{getSelectedClass(item, selectedValue)}}">
          <template is="dom-if" if="{{isSelected(item,selectedValue)}}">
            yes
          </template>
          <button type="button" on-click="selectItem">{{item.label}}</button>
        </li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </template>

  <script>
    var SELECTED_CLASS = 'is-selected';

    Polymer({

      is: 'selectable-list',

      properties: {
        items: {
          type: Array,
          value: function() {
            return [{
              "label": "Item 1",
              "value": 0
            }, {
              "label": "Item 2",
              "value": 1
            }, {
              "label": "Item 3",
              "value": 2
            }]
          }
        },
        selectedValue: {
          type: Object,
          notify: true,
          reflectToAttribute: true
        }
      },

      selectItem: function(event) {
        this.selectedValue = event.model.item.value;
      },


      /**
       * check if a list item is selected
       *
       * @param {object} item
       * @returns {boolean}
       */
      isSelected: function(item, selectedValue) {
        return item.value === selectedValue;
      },


      /**
       * get selected class if item is selected
       * @param {object} item
       * @returns {string}
       */
      getSelectedClass: function(item, selectedValue) {
        return this.isSelected(item, selectedValue) ? SELECTED_CLASS : '';
      }

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>


<selectable-list></selectable-list>
```

Comment: Its working. Coming from an angular world i suggested all this works out of the box and nearly come crazy after struggling with this for some hours. Thanks a lot!